# how to convert json array to an ordered collection in java

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have a scenario in java web service to accept json object as input.Here json object doesn't ensure order.so is there any provision  to convert this input json object to an ordered collection in `java before` reading it?

@Post

```
public Representation updateTestData(JSONObject entity) {
    Representation rep = null;
    JSONObject reqText;
    try {
        reqText = entity;
  //when i'm reading the json object. attributes and  values of json are not in order as that in submit
        log.info("input data: " + reqText);         
                } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("EXCEPTION CAUGHT WHILE UPDATETESTDATA: " + getRequest().getResourceRef().toString()
                + " message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return rep;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to transform the JSON in Java Object, get the list and sort it ?

Comment: Did you try some thing? Could you please put your code to better help you ?

Comment: @Nevin Please, edit your original post, instead of put the code in commentary

Comment: Here order is missing when reading the json object.I want the same order in which i' m getting as input

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear enough, why do you need the JSON request to be in some order ? if you want to get a `name` attribute doesn't matter the order of the json...

Comment: Actually the problem here is i am displaying a dynamic content coming from server in a Angular js data table, i dont know how many columns and rows coming from the server, i am just dumping the data to data table.  When i try to edit the data table data by displaying in a pop up and click save button, i am saving the edited data into json object and sending to server, when i try to read the json at server side the order is different from the order which data displayed on UI, the same order i am saving into DB, so next time when i try to display the edited data on UI previous order is missing.

Comment: Presumably the raw JSON string coming the server is in the correct order? If the order is important, you probably need to parse the string yourself. Parse the JSON string from the request body into a LinkedHashMap, which will preserve the insertion order; most, if not all, JSON to Java libraries will accept a map.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the json structure, change it like this: `[{key:value},{key2:value},...]`, this ensures the order. But if not, then you have to put an additional array to store the order.
it looks dumb though. hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In Json Object, Element are not in sorted order

Comment: Is this the answer user is expecting?

Comment: This is a comment not a solution.

Comment: not actually .Here order is missing when reading the json object.I want the same order in which i' m getting as input